# Where is the pantheon GitHub repository?

Tags: pantheon

I am interested in following the development of Pantheon. I assumed there was a GitHub repo but couldn't seem to find it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the repository of elementary.
[github repository](https://github.com/elementary)

Comment: Of course, and this is the [filter for pantheon related repos](https://github.com/elementary?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pantheon&type=&language=) for the ElementaryOS org.

For some reason, I thought that Pantheon was a separate project at this point, which had _started_ with ElementaryOS but had been extracted into its own thing.